# How to get child product _id in magento2?

Tags: javascript, product-attribute, magento2.2, wishlist, php-7

I can get attribute _color.

Now, How to get the selected **child `product_id`** in **`wishlist.js`** file in Magento2.

If anyone knows please help me.